# What is the purpose of java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture#allOf?

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

If I have `Collection<CompletableFuture<MyResult>>`, I expect to convert this into `CompletableFuture<Collection<MyResult>>`. So after conversion I have only one future and can easyly write bussines logic on `MyResult` collection using methods from `CompletableFuture` like `thenApply`, `thenAccept` etc. But `CompletableFuture#allOf` have result type `Void` so after invoking it I get "no results". E.g. I can not retrieve (as I understand) any results from returned future that correspods to `Collection<CompletableFuture<MyResult>>`.

I have a doubt that `CompletableFuture#allOf` just return the Future wich is completed after all in collection. So I can invoke `CompletableFuture#allOf(...).isDone` and then `manually` **(!)** in cycle tranform `Collection<CompletableFuture>` to `CompletableFuture<Collection>`, Is my assumption right?

Comment: Your assumption is correct.  `allOf` doesn't supply any data but rather it lets you trigger further computations when all futures have completed.  You can then use the triggered `CompletionStage` to reassemble the results into a collection or do whatever else is appropriate.  See the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/30025428/3920048 for some examples of how to make a list of futures into a future of list.

Comment: This is one of the things why I still find [Guava's `Futures.allAsList()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture...)) method incredibly useful.

Comment: @Misha - that should be an answer in imho.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `allOf` method does not supply data, but does signal that all futures have been completed. This eliminates the need of using the more cumbersome countdown latch approach. The expectation is that you would then convert the completed futures back into a usable `Collection` to apply your business logic. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025428/listfuture-to-futurelist-sequence) for implementation details. A great discussion of this topic is available [at this blog post](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-completablefuture-in-action.html).

Answer (score 0):

if you need `CompletableFuture<Collection<MyResult>>` as result you can get  it by using allAsList method in https://github.com/spotify/completable-futures  (spotify-completlablefutures library). `CompletableFutures.allAsList(List<CompletableFuture<MyResult>>)` will give you `CompletableFuture<List<MyResult>>`.