# How process CompletionStage with spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, future, completable-future

How configure spring to work with `CompletionStage` return types? Consider a code:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/", params = "p", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public CompletionStage<List<MyResult>> search(@RequestParam("p") String p) {
    CompletionStage<List<MyResult>> results = ...
    return results;
}
```

I got 404, but I see in log that method is triggered.
If I change signature like that:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/", params = "p", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public List<MyResult> search(@RequestParam("p") String p) {
    CompletionStage<List<MyResult>> results = ...
    return results.get();
}
```

I see successfull json array.

How to make `CompletionStage` works with spring (4.2.RELEASE)?

**UPDATED**

For test I wrote following methods:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/async")
@ResponseBody
public CompletableFuture<List<MyResult>> async() {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Arrays.asList(new MyResult("John"), new MyResult("Bob")));
}
```

And it works. Oo

I have test this version of future:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/async2")
@ResponseBody
public CompletableFuture<List<MyResult>> async2() {
    AsyncRestTemplate template = new AsyncRestTemplate();
    //simulate delay future with execution delay, you can change url to another one
    return toCompletable(template.getForEntity("https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#q=1234567890-", String.class))
            .thenApply(
                    resp -> template.getForEntity("https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#q=1234567890-", String.class))
            .thenApply(
                    resp -> template.getForEntity("https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#q=1234567890-", String.class))
            .thenApply(
                    resp -> template.getForEntity("https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#q=1234567890-", String.class))
            .thenApply(
                    resp -> template.getForEntity("https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#q=1234567890-", String.class))
            .thenApply(
                    resp -> template.getForEntity("https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#q=1234567890-", String.class))
            .thenApply(resp -> Arrays.asList(new MyResult("John"), new MyResult("Bob")));
}
```

A bit agly, but ... works!

So my original method has the following logic:

1. Iterate over Collection
2. Make async call via AsyncRestTemplate for each collection element
3. Make call to each CompletableFuture in collection

   - `thenApply` (transform result)
   - `thenCompose` (make new async call with AsyncRestTemplate)
   - `thenApply` (transform result)
   - At the end I call transform List to Completable as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30026710/1251549).

It seem that Future transformation is wrong. Can it be that future chain eecutes too long? Any ideas?

Comment: That should be available by default. Post the error / logs you get on the server. (As an edit not as comments!).

Comment: Updated. There are no erros in logs, but I have done some experiments, may it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in that line:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/" ...
```

When changed it to

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/1" ...
```

Future completion suddenly become working.

**P.S.** I had broken all my mind before found that the problem actually in the mapping. May helps for someone O:-)