# Java 8 maintain stream order with CompletableFuture::join

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, completable-future

I have an input stream of queries which are getting executed asynchronously. I want to make sure that when I use `Completablefuture::join`, the result of those requires are collected int the order of input query stream.

This is how my code looks like:

```
queries.stream()
     .map(query -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                    try {
                        return SQLQueryEngine.execute(query);
                    } catch (InternalErrorException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
     }))
     .map(CompletableFuture::join)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

SQLQueryEngine.execute(query); returns a `List<Results>` so output is `List<List<Result>`. I want to flatten and combine all the results into one single List. If i use .flatMap(List::stream) before collection to flatten, will it maintain the ordering?

Comment: Misha has already provided the answer. As a sidenote, keep in mind that you are executing the queries _sequentially_, as you wait for the response of each `CompletableFuture` one after the other (join in the map). If you want to process them _concurrently_, map the stream to a `List` of `CompletableFutures`, and call `allOf` on them. Example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025428/listfuture-to-futurelist-sequence)

Comment: Thanks @Ruben for pointing this out :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably meant `.flatMap` and yes, it will retain the ordering.

Consider explicitly passing an `Executor` to `supplyAsync` to avoid scheduling your IO-bound sql queries in `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`.

As @Ruben [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361983/java-8-maintain-stream-order-with-completablefuturejoin/33362192#comment54521094_33361983), you are joining each task in the current thread immediately after submitting it and *before* submitting the next query, which is likely a bug.  You should submit all queries first and only then start joining.

You can do it like this (with static import of `toList`):

```
queries.stream()
    .map(query -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(...))
    .collect(toList())
    .stream()
    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
    .collect(toList());
```

Comment: The code in its current form won’t pollute the common pool to much, as it `join`s each future right after its submission.

Comment: True, assuming that this is the only thread and nothing else is happening that might be scheduling tasks into the common pool.  Even if for a particular application there's no harm in running blocking tasks in the common pool, it's just a bad habit to get into.

Comment: Right, especially as joining each task immediately doesn’t seem to be intentional. So from this point of view, my comment was more of sarcasm…

Comment: Apparently, my sarcasm detector was offline due to insufficient caffeine intake.  I think it's best I incorporate @Ruben's comment into the answer.

Comment: Thanks @misha. I din't realize that I was executing the queries sequentially. And Yes I meant flatMap. This is very insightful.

I believe your solution of doing .collect().stream() before .map(Completable::join) has the same effect as using CompletableFuture::allOf. 

Also one more question about your suggestion of passing Executor to supplyAsyc to avoid polluting the common pool, is there a recommend way on how to do this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163108/custom-thread-pool-in-java-8-parallel-stream, suggests creating a new fork pool and passing it along to supply async

Comment: Yes, it will have the same effect as `allOf`, but it's shorter and is good enough because you are joining right there in the current thread.  `allOf` would let you queue up further computations without joining, but you don't need that.  As for which `Executor` to pass to `supplyAsync`, `java.util.concurrent.Executors` has factory methods to construct various Executors.  If you have questions about choosing the most appropriate `Executor`, submit a new question.

Comment: Thanks @misha, I posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377177/how-to-chose-an-executor-for-completablefuturesupplyasync

Comment: @Misha .. isnt this blocking one by one.. So we will get Sum of all latencies rather than Max(Latencies)