# Why is CompletableFuture.allOf declared as CompletableFuture<Void>?

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, completable-future

Why is `CompletableFuture.allOf` declared as `CompletableFuture<Void>` and not returning collection of results or something else? I think that was good idea to make `CompletableFuture.anyOf` return `CompletableFuture<Object>`, but I see these two methods connected and so I'm confused about what they return.

Comment: That would require creating the `List` in advance, even if the caller never queries it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`anyOf` has to somehow tell you what was the result of the specific `CompletableFuture` whose completion triggered `anyOf`.  That's not necessary in case of `allOf` because you know which futures completed -- all of them.

`allOf` (just as `anyOf`) doesn't require that all futures bear the same type.  So if it were to return a future of collection, it would have to be a collection of `Object` which is probably not what you want anyway.

If you really want to have `allOf` return a future of collection, it's fairly straightforward to write your own:

```
public static CompletableFuture<List<Object>> myAllOf(CompletableFuture<?>... futures) {
     return CompletableFuture.allOf(futures)
            .thenApply(x -> Arrays.stream(futures)
                    .map(f -> (Object) f.join())
                    .collect(toList())
            );
}
```

If you have a type-safe version of this problem and need to convert a collection of futures of a certain type to a future of collection of that same type, see this question for several examples: [List<Future> to Future<List> sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30025428/3920048)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but anyway I cant understand why `allOf` cant return stream of CompletableFuture or results or smth else...

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Misha's answer, but with a generic type:

```
public class Futures {
    public static <T> CompletableFuture<List<T>> all(List<CompletableFuture<T>> futures) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> cfv = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
        return cfv.thenApply(future -> {
            return futures.stream()
                    .map(completableFuture -> completableFuture.join())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        });
    }
}
```

That's the method the Java API should provide.