# Java 8 CompletableFuture.allOf(...) with Collection or List

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

Java 8 has a function [`CompletableFuture.allOf(CompletableFuture<?>...cfs)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) that returns a `CompletableFuture` that is completed when all the given futures complete.

However, I almost always am not dealing with an array of `CompletableFuture`s, but instead have a `List<CompletableFuture>`.  Of course, I can use the `toArray()` method, but this ends up being a bit of a pain to have to constantly convert back and forth between arrays and lists.

It would be really nice if there were a slick way get a `CompletableFuture<List<T>>` in exchange for a `List<CompletableFuture<T>>`, instead of constantly having to throw in an intermediary array creation. Does anyone know a way to do this in Java 8?

Answer (score 86):

Unfortunately, to my knowledge CompletableFuture does not support collections.

You could do something like this to make the code a bit cleaner, but it essentially does the same thing

```
public <T> CompletableFuture<List<T>> allOf(List<CompletableFuture<T>> futuresList) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> allFuturesResult =
    CompletableFuture.allOf(futuresList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futuresList.size()]));
    return allFuturesResult.thenApply(v ->
            futuresList.stream().
                    map(future -> future.join()).
                    collect(Collectors.<T>toList())
    );
}
```

Found this very informative : http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-completablefuture-in-action.html

Comment: Use `CompletableFuture.allOf(futuresList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futuresList.size()]))` since CompletableFuture.allOf() takes in an array of `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: @wz366 this works but I'm getting a warning from IntelliJ on `new CompletableFuture[futuresList.size()]` saying `Array of type Object[]` expected

Comment: I don't understand the benefit of using `allOf` in combination with `join` method. You could directly write `return futuresList.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: I also found this tutorial very helpful and best explanation I've found so far on CompletableFuture: https://www.callicoder.com/java-8-completablefuture-tutorial/

Comment: @OlivierBoissé sometime we don't want to block the thread and just simply what to wrap the list of futures into a single returnable future for other logic to consume

Comment: @OlivierBoissé it's about exceptions. If one of your futures completed with exception - your code will not wait for completion of all futures. While `allOf` will work as expected.

Comment: @OlivierBoissé when you write `return futuresList.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList());` you are waiting right at this point for completion of all futures. In contrast, `return CompletableFuture.allOf( futuresList.toArray(new CompletableFuture<?>[0])).thenApply(v -> futuresList.stream() .map(future -> future.join()) .collect(Collectors.<T>toList()) );` does not wait for any future but returns a new future which will get completed with the result list once all futures are completed.

Comment: final List<CompletableFuture<Module> futures= ....
              CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.stream().toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join();

Comment: Just to clear up some possible confusion on that inner `future.join()`:  _"...Since we’re calling future.join() after all the futures are complete, we’re not blocking anywhere."_ Meaning, we're just getting the result of already completed future.

Taken from [callicoder.com/java-8-completablefuture-tutorial](https://www.callicoder.com/java-8-completablefuture-tutorial/)

Comment: Use `futuresList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])` instead of `futuresList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futuresList.size()])` on HotSpot 8. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174093/toarraynew-myclass0-or-toarraynew-myclassmylist-size)