# How to get result of list of futures

Tags: java

I have List of futures

```
List<Future<Boolean>> futures = service.invokeAll( Arrays.asList( callable1, callable2 ));
```

what i need is a way to get a list of results

can you provide a solution in java?

something like `whenAll()...`

Comment: No, we are here to help you, but you´ll need to deliver your attempt first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30025428/1553934 look at this question. I think what you're looking for is `CompletableFuture.allOf(...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are after is the `allMatch()` method like this:

```
boolean result = futures.stream().allMatch(booleanFuture -> {
    try
    {
        return booleanFuture.get();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
});
```

If you really meant a list of results, then it is `map()` you are after like this:

```
List<Boolean> results = futures.stream().map(booleanFuture -> {
    try
    {
        return booleanFuture.get();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifiying @Vampire 's results
You can also use a parallelStream like one shown below if it is a lot of data

```
 List<Boolean> results = futures.parallelStream().map(booleanFuture -> {
        try
        {
            return booleanFuture.get();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```