# Zip process with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java

I would like to know which is the official mechanism to do `zip` using `CompletableFuture`.
So far I just use `thenCombine` operator. Here my example.

```
@Test
public void zip() throws InterruptedException {
    CompletableFuture<Either<Integer, String>> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::getValue);
    CompletableFuture<Either<Integer, String>> completableFuture1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::getValue);
    CompletableFuture<Either<Integer, String>> completableFuture2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::getValue);

    completableFuture
            .thenCombine(completableFuture1, (c1, c2) -> new Right<>(c1.right().get() + "|" + c2.right().get()))
            .thenCombine(completableFuture2, (c1, c2) -> new Right<>(c1.right().get() + "|" + c2.right().get()))

            .whenComplete((result, throwable) -> System.out.println(result.right().get()));
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

For me the use of `thenCombine` operator is more like `merge` operator of `RxJava`.

Any idea if there´s a better way to do it?.

I just want run three process in parallel and the zip the results.

Regards.

Comment: consider a stream of completable futures and reducing that stream?

Comment: Sorry I don't exactly get it, can you provide an example using Stream with the completable future?. I have an API that return CompletableFuture, so I need to zip all them. Still I understand then that completableFuture does not have a operator to make zip of N process?

Comment: if you need pairwise N:1 reduction  then CompletableFuture does not provide that since it only deals with one or at most two elements (i.e. the pairwise part, not the N part). The whole "operate on N elements" thing is orthogonal to asynchronous execution and provided through collections or streams. Basically you're expecting CFs to provide two features where it is only a building block and the other feature is provided by another one.

Comment: Since you tagged RxJava, why don't you use RxJava's `zip`?

Comment: Since the API that I'm consuming is returning CF. I can transform one to another but my question here was. Provide  CF an operator to do Zip. And seems like it does not

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025428/listfuture-to-futurelist-sequence)? It sounds like `CompletableFuture.allOf` suits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

There indeed does not seem to exist any direct equivalent of RxJava's `zip` (e.g. Single.zip) for CompletableFuture. `CompletableFuture.allOf` comes close, but does not give you any combined response value.

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf(java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...)) says:

> Otherwise, the results, if any, of the given CompletableFutures are not reflected in the returned CompletableFuture, but may be obtained by inspecting them individually.

Using this, it would not be too hard to build some `Single.zip`-like wrappers on top of CompletableFuture.allOf. Here is one for the form that takes two CompletableFutures:

```java
class Zip {
  static <T1, T2, R> CompletableFuture<R> zip(CompletableFuture<T1> t1, CompletableFuture<T2> t2, BiFunction<T1, T2, R> combine) {
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(t1, t2).thenApply(ignored -> combine.apply(get(t1), get(t2)));
  }

  private static <T> T get(CompletableFuture<T> completableFuture) {
    // This will only be used for CompletableFutures that we know have
    // completed with a result.
    try {
      return completableFuture.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I here used Java's built-in `BiFunction` interface for the combiner, for variants of larger arity we need to define our own interface:

```java
interface Function3<T1, T2, T3, R> {
  R apply(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3);
}


class Zip {
  // ...

  static <T1, T2, T3, R> CompletableFuture<R> zip(CompletableFuture<T1> t1, CompletableFuture<T2> t2, CompletableFuture<T3> t3, Function3<T1, T2, T3, R> combine) {
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(t1, t2, t3).thenApply(ignored -> combine.apply(get(t1), get(t2), get(t3)));
  }
}
```

(Note: I have briefly tested that these methods work, but they are not battle-tested in a production app.)