# How to convert Collection<CompletableFuture<X>> to CompletableFuture<Collection<X>> without calling join or get?

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

Given a collection of futures

```
final Collection<CompletableFuture<X>> futures = ...;
final CompletableFuture<Collection<X>> joined = ???
```

How to produce a future for a collection with all values combined together, without calling `join`?

Comment: What's your logic for combining those individual futures? I mean, if one of those `CompletableFuture<X>` were to fail or timeout, how should it affect the combined `CompletableFuture<Collection<X>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to

1. Convert `Collection<CompletableFuture<X>>` to `Collection<CompletableFuture<Collection<X>>>`
2. Reduce on this collection using `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Collections.emptyList())`
   as initial value.

```java
final CompletableFuture<Collection<X>> joined = 
                futures
                .stream()
                .map(f -> f.thenApply(value -> (Collection<X>)Collections.singletonList(value)))
                .reduce(
                        CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Collections.emptyList()), 
                        (f, g) -> 
                            f.thenCompose(
                                xs -> g.thenApply(
                                     ys -> Stream
                                               .of(xs, ys)
                                               .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                               .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                                )
                            );
```

Comment: This is a good method

Comment: what you have shown here is pretty much the same thing as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32667118/1059372), from the duplicate

Comment: the problem with this btw, is that `thenCompose/thenApply` can be easily executed in the `main` thread, but otherwise I think this looks nice.